# how to bind mouseover, click events on element inside jsrender template

Tags: jsrender

I am using jsRender and want to bind events like click, mouse over on elements that get render  inside the template.  while binding the event , I want to pass the data as a argument.

Example :

```
<li id="liv_{{:nid}}" onmouseover=[call some function and pass #data]>
<div class="qwqw"><a href="#"></a></div>
<div class="">
    <p class="we">{{:spd}} <span>mph (todo)</span></p>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
```

I tried the code as mentioned above but didnt worked. Can someone give insight into how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As long as the function you want to call in the `onmouseover` event is defined, this is trivial:

```
<li id="liv_{{:nid}}" onmouseover="someFunction({{:#data}});"> </li>
```

However, it's probabaly cleaner to just bind these events after rendering with jQuery.  I can imagine applying a `data-*` attribute to all of these list items and using that in your selector.

Answer (score 0):

`{{:#data}}` renders #data as a string, so **that approach won't work unless #data stringifies and parses neatly**. Objects won't stringify or parse neatly without manual JSON usage. In fact, I suspect only numbers, booleans, `undefined`, and `null` will stringify and parse correctly. That approach **also** won't work **if the function is not global**. Being forced to define the callback function globally any time you want to do this strikes me as a severe problem. So I can't recommend using in-tag event-handlers, especially when you already have JavaScript running.

**Instead**, after you insert your rendered content into the DOM, you can bind the event there. Here's a rough sketch.

Add a class or some other selector-fodder to your `<li>`.

```
<li class="onMouseEnter" id="liv_{{:nid}}"></li>
```

Put each of your #data values into an object using an equivalent of `liv_{{:nid}}` as the key.

```
var dataMap = {};
$.each(yourDataValues, function (i, value) {
    dataMap['liv_' + value.nid] = value;
});
```

Lastly, bind a live event to the container into which you pushed your rendered template.

```
$(containerOfRenderedTemplate).on('mouseenter', '.onMouseEnter', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var data = dataMap[id];
    desiredCallbackFunctionWhichConsumesData(data);
});
```

`dataMap` and the event-binding call should be within the same scope.

**Note:** If this rendering can happen more than once, and you need to replace the rendered content with all-new rendered content, you should unbind the old event before binding the new one.

```
$(containerOfRenderedTemplate).off('mouseenter', '.onMouseEnter');
```